# Score Count not working on a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is semi complicated of a question but I'll do my best to explain it:

I am making this mobile game in which you have to shoot four cubes. I'm trying to make it so when the cubes are shot by a bullet, they're destroyed and a UI text says 1/4, to 4/4 whenever a cube is shot. But it's being really weird and only counts to 1/4 even when all four cubes are shot and destroyed. I put these two scripts on the bullets (I made two separate scripts to see if that would do anything, it didn't)

And to give a better idea of what I'm talking about, here's a screenshot of the game itself.[image]

I've been using Unity for about 6 days, so I apologize for anything I say that's noob-ish.

**EDIT**

So I combined the two scripts onto an empty gameobject and here's the new script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class GameManagerScript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject cubes;
public Text countText;
public int cubeCount;
public Transform target;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    cubes = other.gameObject;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    cubes.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, 1f * Time.deltaTime);


    if (cubes.gameObject.tag == "BULLET")
    {

        cubeCount = cubeCount + 1;
        countText.text = cubeCount + "/4";
        cubes.SetActive(false);
    }
}
}
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I tried everything, so is there a way to detect when all the children in a parent on the Hierarchy are destroyed? Instead of counting up? This can give a better idea:

[image: cubes]

So I want to be able to detect when Cube, Cube1, Cube2, and Cube3 have all been destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: Since every individual bullet has that script, each bullet has its own score.

For something like a score you want a single spot to store it, e.g. a script on an empty gameobject that serves as game controller. Just access that in the collision and increase the score (maybe have a look on singletons here).

You can combine those two scripts and actually it might be better to not have this on the bullet, but on the target because there are probably less of them which will save you some performance. (And it does more sense from a logical point of view.)

**Edit:**
I assume you create the bullets using `Instantiate` with a prefab. A prefab (= blueprint) is not actually in the game (only objects that are in the scene/hierarchy are in the game). Every use of Instantiate will create a new instance of that prefab with it's own version of components. A singleton is a thing that can only exist once, but also and that is why I mention it here, you can access it without something like `Find`. It is some sort of static. And an empty gameobject is just an object without visuals. You can easily create one in unity (rightclick > create empty). They are typically used as container and scriptholders.

**Edit:**
What you want is:

- An empty gameobject with a script which holds the score.
- A script that detects the collision using `OnTriggerEnter` and this script will either be on the bullets or on the targets.

Now, this is just a very quick example and can be optimized, but I hope this will give you an idea.
The script for the score, to be placed on an empty gameobject:

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;    // the text object that displays the score, populate e.g. via inspector

    private int score;

    public void IncrementScore()
    {
        score++;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
}
```

The collision script as bullet version:

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ScoreManager scoreManager;

    private void Start()
    {
        scoreManager = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<ScoreManager>();    // give the score manager empty gameobject that tag
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Target") == true)
        {
             // update score
             scoreManager.IncrementScore();
             // handle target, in this example it's just destroyed
             Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is only one bullet I believe, I followed a tutorial for bullets and they come out of a bullet emitter gameobject on the gun,just respawning over and over again. I could be wrong though, but I tried combining the two scripts as one on the four targets, and the same thing still happens. Can you explain how to use an empty gameobject? I'm not sure what a singleton is. Thanks

Comment: @JuanFranciscoPatino I added some stuff to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, I edited my answer too asking you another question.

Comment: Ah, you missunderstood me :) The `OnCollisionEnter` stuff stays on either the bullet or the cubes. Just the score moves to an empty. Maybe have a look at this tutorial. Has some annotations for the new GUI. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/counting-points-and-displaying-score

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that

Comment: I tried everything :( there's one more possible option I think: is there a way to detect when all the children in the parent have been destroyed/shot? So then instead of counting, my game can just tell the player when they destroyed all the cubes.

Comment: Please edit your question to match your current state if it changed. It should definitly be possible to achieve what you want with `OnTrigger`.

Comment: Just did, and I've been using OnTriggerEnter.

Comment: Yes, but if that is your current version, it is not where it needs to be. Have a look on my other edit.

Comment: I just put both scripts into my compiler, and where you said "scoreText = score.ToString();" I get an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'". As well as a red underline underneath "ScoreManager" in "private Scoremanager scoreManager;". I named the empty gameObject GameManager by the way, but even when I change it to "GameManager'" instead of "ScoreManager" it gives me a different error. And if I'm asking for a lot, I appreciate what you've done so far.

Comment: Ah, yes, should be `scoreText.text = score.ToString();`. That private has to have the name of the script you want to reference, in my case `ScoreManager`. Needs be the exact same. Use the auto-complete function, if you have it saved (make sure you did that), it should be found.

Comment: I fixed the first error, but when I change "ScoreManager" to the name of my script, it gives me a red line under "scoreManager = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager"); " The error says "Severity Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'GameManagerScript (Name of my ScoreManager script)'"

Comment: Man, I'm not up to it. Needs to be `GameObject.FindWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<ScoreManager>()`.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you so much for all this, idk what I would do if I couldn't fix this. Again, thank you so much!